# Tabula-py does not read horizontal tables correctly

Tags: python, list, tabular, tabula, tabula-py

[image]I'm trying to read data from a pdf with multiple tables. there are 5 tables with the data and one empty table. Except empty table 3 of them are vertical table and 2 of them are horizontal. All vertical table's data are correct but when tabula trying to read horizontal tables it still reads as vertical table.[image]
How can I solve this?

I read the documentation tabula but I couldn't find any related thing to horizontal table reading

Comment: I don't know why you even posted the picture if all the data is gone.  PDFs were not designed to be read like this.  It is doing the best that it can.  Surely you can find a way to work with the data you have, if the data is not there.

Comment: Data is still there. When I posting that pdf,  I have to hide that due to privacy issue.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, as long as you have the data, it's very easy to reformat it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to highlight the table that I showed. now you can see the table (framed by red line) in the pdf and the result when I tried to read from tabula.

Comment: Yes, I understood all of that.  You HAVE all the data you want.  If it's not formatted the way you want to see it, then YOU need to reformat it.  Just that easy.